# Does a 0-fold Cartesian product exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Knowing that for a set $S$ that the $n$-fold Cartesian product is $S \times S \times S\times\cdots$  $n$ times, can $n$ be equal to zero?
(Note: A Cartesian product is not the same as 'just' a set.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is A Set Raised to the 0 Power? (In Relation to the Definition of a Nullary Operation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921712/what-is-a-set-raised-to-the-0-power-in-relation-to-the-definition-of-a-nullary)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827670/empty-cartesian-product-what-is-mathbbr0 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205234/what-is-the-cartesian-product-of-an-empty-set-of-sets

Comment: What do you think a Cartesian product _is_, if not a set?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, $n$ can be zero. The cartesian product of the empty family of sets is a singleton consisting of just the empty tuple.

Comment: +1. This is also called the [Nullary Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product#Nullary_Cartesian_product).